# how to pattern match a list head and tail in purescript

Tags: purescript

I'm doing this in the psci repl. This is my function:

```
$> import Data.List
$> let f (x:xs) = x
$> let f Nil = Nil

$> let a = 1:2:3:Nil

$> f a
```

I get this error:

```
  Could not match type

    Int

  with type

    List t0


while trying to match type List Int
  with type List (List t0)
while checking that expression a
  has type List (List t0)
in value declaration it

where t0 is an unknown type
```

I understand this is happening because my function `f` does not have a signature that returns `List Int`. But how do I declare one in the repl?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is `f` is returning two different types:

```
let f (x:xs) = x
```

is returning an element of the list (so `a`, or `Int` in the case of `f a`), whereas

```
let f Nil = Nil
```

is returning a `List`.

Comment: How do I fix it so that `f` returns a `Maybe` type?

Comment: `f (x:xs) = Just x`
`f Nil = Nothing`